# PhoneGap Build admob

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-pushplugin, phonegap-admob

I have problems with phonegap build , admob not show... How can i show it?

This is my js file

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/createjs-2013.09.25.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sounds.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/admob.js"></script>
```

This is my main function that start game.

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                     var oMain = new CMain({
                                    min_reel_loop:2,          
                                    reel_delay: 6,            
                                    time_show_win:2000,       
                                    time_show_all_wins: 2000, 
                                    money:3000                
                                });

                     $(oMain).on("game_start", function(evt) {
                             //alert("game_start");
                     });

                     $(oMain).on("end_bet", function(evt,iMoney,iBetWin) {
                             //alert("iMoney: "+iMoney + " Win:"+iBetWin);
                     });

                     $(oMain).on("restart", function(evt) {
                             //alert("restart");
                     });

           });
        </script>
```

Comment: remove cordova.js or phonegap.js, you shouldn't use both, just one of them. And add a link to the plugin you are using, there are plenty of them.

Comment: Ok i have just delete phonegap.js, but i want integrate in my main js function when start game show banner.

Comment: link to the plugin you are using?

Comment: Yes, i use an config.xml file with :  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.google.cordova.admob" source="plugins.cordova.io" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.Device"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [documentation of the AdMob plugin](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob/blob/master/test/index.html), more specifically, you need this function to create the banner with your custom settings:

```
window.plugins.AdMob.setOptions( {
publisherId: admobid.banner,
interstitialAdId: admobid.interstitial,
bannerAtTop: false, // set to true, to put banner at top
overlap: false, // set to true, to allow banner overlap webview
offsetTopBar: false, // set to true to avoid ios7 status bar overlap
isTesting: false, // receiving test ad
autoShow: true // auto show interstitial ad when loaded
});
```

The example index.html I linked is ready to use and show ads with your specific settings.

Comment: oK, but how can i integrate in my code ...  i want show banner when start game. I download example code and work, but i don't know how can i integrate in my main js function.Thanks

Comment: @wpcard you must copy, paste and edit the relevant sections, the original code is well commented... I can't program the game for you, I can only provide you the references to point you in the right direction, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your comment about how to show the ad at the beginning of game, and using the plugin here: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova you should do like this:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

  // Set AdMobAds options:
  admob.setOptions({
    publisherId:          "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",  // Required
    interstitialAdId:     "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII",  // Optional
  });

  // Start showing banners (atomatic when autoShowBanner is set to true)
  admob.createBannerView();
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```